# Can I configure the file name while generating scripts in Object explorer

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. While generating scripts for the objects (as one file each for object) it appends the object type to the file - like this: `<tableName>.table.sql`.

Is there any configuration setting that can be used to change or follow a templated naming style?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a configuration property that allows you to define how the files are named. Your best bet is to write a script in your language of choice to do a bulk file rename operation on the files. The format of the existing file names are already defined, so it shouldn't be too difficult.